# Jenkins fail build after executing all commands if exit code != 0

Tags: shell, jenkins

I'm trying to run multiple commands in a single shell execution build step. If one of those commands exits on a code other than 0, the build will fail immediately. This is how it is by default.

I want for the build to continue executing all the commands in this build step even if one or more exit code 0 are given. After all these commands are executed, I want my build to fail if the exit code is anything other than 0.

Is there any way to do this by just using console commands and not using a (shell) script?

These commands are the ones I'm trying to execute:

```
git diff origin/develop --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep .php | xargs -n1 -P8 php -l
git diff origin/develop --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep .php | xargs -n1 phpcs --standard=PSR2
git diff origin/develop --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep .php | xargs -n1 -I file phpmd file text cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode
```

As you might know these are for php code analysis and I want to know *everything* that's wrong before failing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a variable to record if one of them fails and then check if that variable is set at the end of the script:

```
FAILURE=0
command1 || FAILURE=1
command2 || FAILURE=1
command3 || FAILURE=1

if [ $FAILURE -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "One or more failures!
  exit 1
fi
```

So in your case:

```
FAILURE=0
git diff origin/develop --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep .php | xargs -n1 -P8 php -l || FAILURE=1
git diff origin/develop --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep .php | xargs -n1 phpcs --standard=PSR2 || FAILURE=1
git diff origin/develop --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep .php | xargs -n1 -I file phpmd file text cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode || FAILURE=1

if [ $FAILURE -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "One or more failures!
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

With shell, you can do:

```
command || true;
```

In order to allow the command to fail.

Comment: Indeed, yet that will make the build pass even if there are errors in any of those commands.